# Open link in the browser with electron doesen't work

Tags: javascript, electron

I tried this BUT it doesn't work because my link is a `div`. Here is my JS:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.href.startsWith('http')) {
    event.preventDefault()
    shell.openExternal(event.target.href)
  }
})
```

Works with this HTML:

```
<a style="display:block;color:white;text-decoration:none;" href="https://discord.com/">Test</a>
```

Does not work with:

```
<a style="display:block;color:white;text-decoration:none;" href="https://discord.com/"><div class="socialoutline"><img style="width:35px;position:relative;left:7px;top:9px;"src="assets/images/logo/social/discord.svg">&#8195;&#8196;Discord</div></a>
```

Comment: Your first example works as it is a single element. A `click` event will register on that element. Your second example has nested elements. The `click` event will be registering on the `img` or `div` element and not the parent `a` element as the child elements will be "filling" the parent element.